# xcode download as .dmg file

Tags: iphone, xcode, dmg

i am new with Xcode and Iphone.

**I had just download whole Xcode4.2 but it comes as .dmg file.**

Size is 1.62GB..

**I just wanna know that how can open this to Xcode folder.**

Can any buddy help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm a Windows person and I know how to do this...)

Mount it. (Context menu, double-click, Return, doesn't matter.) A drive will appear on your desktop. Open that. In fact, it will probably already be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[Installing Xcode 4](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_Xcode_4_and_the_iOS_5_SDK)